# assignment of member ' in read-only object

Tags: c++

```
protected:
DWORD               m_dwMountTime;

public:
    DWORD GetLastHorseTime() const {
        return m_dwHorseTime;
    }


    DWORD CHARACTER::GetMyHorseVnum() const {
        int delta = 0;
        m_dwMountTime = get_dword_time();

        return c_aHorseStat[GetHorseLevel()].iNPCRace + delta;
    }
```

ok, there is my code.

After when i try to compile i get an error :

```
    char_horse.cpp: In member function 'virtual DWORD CHARACTER::GetMyHorseVnum() const':
    char_horse.cpp:210:16: error: assignment of member 'CHARACTER::m_dwHorseTime' in read-only object

  m_dwHorseTime = get_dword_time();
```

Where is the problem? :)

Answer (score 2):

A member function marked `const` cannot change the state of the class.  In `GetMyHorseVnum()` you have

```
m_dwMountTime = get_dword_time();
```

Which changes the state of the class.  You either need to get rid of the `const` modifer on the function or make `m_dwMountTime` `mutable`

Answer (score 1):

You declared your `GetMyHorseVnum()` method as `const`, so it cannot change (assigning) class members.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a member variable in a const member function, which promise won't change the state of the class.

You might want to make `m_dwMountTime` [mutable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) to make it modifiable:

```
mutable DWORD m_dwMountTime;
```

> mutable - applies to non-static class members of non-reference
>   non-const type and specifies that the member does not affect the
>   externally visible state of the class (as often used for mutexes, memo
>   caches, lazy evaluation, and access instrumentation). mutable members
>   of const classes are modifiable. (Note: the C++ language grammar
>   treats mutable as a storage-class-specifier, but it does not affect
>   storage class.)